# Determining canonical classes with text data

Tags: cluster-analysis, text-mining, word2vec

I have a unique problem and I'm not aware of any algorithm that can help me. Maybe someone on here does.

I have a dataset compiled from many different sources (teams). One field in particular is called "type". Here are some example values for type:

> aple, apples, appls, ornge, fruits, orange, orange z, pear,
>   cauliflower, colifower, brocli, brocoli, leeks, veg, vegetables.

What I would like to be able to do is to group them together into e.g. fruits, vegetables, etc.

Put another way I have multiple spellings of various permutations of a parent level variable (fruits or vegetables in this example) and I need to be able to group them as best I can.

The only other potentially relevant feature of the data is the team that entered it, assuming some consistency in the way each team enters their data.

So, I have several million records of multiple spellings and short spellings (e.g. apple, appls) and I want to group them together in some way. In this example by fruits and vegetables.

Clustering would be challenging since each entry is most often 1 or two words, making it tricky to calculate a distance between terms.

Short of creating a massive lookup table created by a human (not likely with millions of rows), is there any approach I can take with this problem?

Comment: This isn't a statistical task yet. You have to lemmatize (restore vocabular form) for each word. However, if many words are some unregular, messy abbreviations then even a lemmatizing/stemmatizing software will hardly help. I believe the practicaslly easiest way is to go through the list of that millions words and convert each into its full form first. Some of the recodings you can do automatically beforehand, by anticipastiong most typical misspellings, for example ornge -> orange. Programs like MS Word and some internet sites help fix misspelings fast when checking orthography.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns, assuming I did that and had perfectly spelt data (hopefully there's a magic library in r out there), what would I do then? "Lemmatize" is a new phrase to me. Is my goal to lemmatize the words? Are you aware of any r packages for that? Thanks for the info so far

Comment: What information do you have which would allow you to cluster them together? Does each entry have additional information about the object's greenness or leafiness? "leek" or "apple" is just a meaningless string to the computer -- without extra information, either from the dataset or some external source, there's no algorithm which the computer could use to classify them into "fruit" or "vegetable" -- even humans aren't capable of that, we use external information (what the strings "leek" and "apple" represent, and the properties of those represented objects, such as greenness or taste)as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first solve the spelling problem, unless you have Google scale data that could allow you to learn fixing spelling with Google scale statistics.

Then you will still have the problem that "Apple" could be a fruit or a computer. Apple and "Granny Smith" will be completely different. You best guess at this second stage is something like word2vec trained on *massive* data. Then you get high dimensional word vectors, and can finally try to solve the clustering challenge, if you ever get that far with decent results. Good luck.